# Access controls inside a repeater inside a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

I have a property in my code that sends back the information in a usercontrol that is a repeater. rptOwners is the repeater I am using. The information inside the repeater has to be parsed manually to xml and sent back through a property in the code. The problem is that I can't seem to get access to the values of the controls inside the repeater.

When debugging, I am able to see that there are the 2 items I expected in rptOwners.DataSource and that the rptOwners.Items.Count = 2. I can then see in the watch window that the information I want is there but I can't get access to it.

I have been trying rptOwners.DataSource[0].Name etc but it says that "cannot apply indexing to an expression of type object.

```
public string xmlString
{
    get
    {
        var _builder = new StringBuilder();

        var rpt = rptOwners.DataSource;
        IList<string> ownersRepeater = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in rpt )
        {
            _builder.Append("<Owners>");
            _builder.Append("<Owner>");
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", name));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", address));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", age));
            _builder.Append("</Owner>");
            _builder.Append("</Owners>");
        }
        return _builder.ToString();
    }
```

Thanks for the help. Let me know if this was not clear enough.

Here is more of what I mean...

[image]

Here is the answer:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptOwners.Items)
        {
            var lblOwnerName = (Label)item.FindControl("lblOwnerName");


            _builder.Append("<Owners>");
            _builder.Append("<Owner>");
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", lblOwnerName));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", item));
            _builder.Append("</Owner>");
            _builder.Append("</Owners>");


        }
        return _builder.ToString();
```

Comment: You mean you can't access the DataSource? Or is your DataSource an array of objects and you`re trying to access its elements?

Comment: My datasource is an array of object that are type Owner. Inside owner are the details of each owner. The owner class has been proven working before. It is jsut the trouble of accessing the values to send to another class. My DataSource is an array of objects and I'm trying to access its elements.

Comment: Show DataSource property code.

Comment: And you wrote that rptOwners.Items does not have access to the information you need. Now it seems that it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (i only added a cast):

```
public string xmlString
{
get
{
    var _builder = new StringBuilder();

    var rpt = (IList<Owner>) rptOwners.DataSource; //ADDED A CAST
    IList<string> ownersRepeater = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in rpt )
    {
        _builder.Append("<Owners>");
        _builder.Append("<Owner>");
        _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", name));
        _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", address));
        _builder.Append(String.Format("<item>{0}</item>", age));
        _builder.Append("</Owner>");
        _builder.Append("</Owners>");
    }
    return _builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you need to convert to the exact type, if its not IList<Owner>, put the proper one.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your DataSource property implemented but from your description seems that changing

```
var rpt = rptOwners.DataSource;
```

line to

```
var rpt = rptOwners.Items;
```

should work.

Comment: rptOwners.Items does not have access to the information I need. See image in edited post.

Comment: Still cant understand what type is DataSource. is it `public object[] DataSource` or `public object DataSource`, please post code. Start debugging and with QuickWach look what type is your DataSource. then let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use 'var' wherever you want. It is better to show the exact type if it's not obvious what is the type looking into the right part of expression.

You cannot apply indexer just because Repeater.DataSource property is of type System.Object. You have to cast it to appropriate one to get access to indexer (List?).